# Will making protected methods in Android BillingReceiver make my billing vulnerable?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Will making protected methods in Android `BillingReceiver` make my billing vulnerable?

Thanks.

Comment: Its not a direct answer to your question but if you have not read the security suggestions from Android it would be good to do so. http://developer.android.com/guide/google/play/billing/billing_best_practices.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not *per se*.

However, relying solely on the Java language access modifiers for data protection will mean that your application is potentially vulnerable.  If the bad guy can run code in your VM and use the reflection APIs, it is simple to route around Java language access modifiers and access `private` fields and methods.

If the "bad guys" you are worried about are the owners of the devices, you should assume that they can subvert any code that is run on their devices.  (This might be technically difficult, but it only takes one smart and motivated person to figure it out ... and the cat is out of the bag.)